# Composition of functions Discrete Math question

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

How do I do this? All help is appreciated! Would prefer a step by step tutorial but any help is ok :)

> Let $h= g\circ f\circ g$ where $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb Z$ is the floor function and $g \colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R \colon x\mapsto -x$.
>   (i)  Compute $h(3.4)$, $h(7)$ and $h(-1.3)$.
>   (ii) Describe what $h$ is doing to a general real number $x$.
>   [image: Question:]

Comment: HINT: $f(x)=\lfloor{x}\rfloor, g(x)=-x, h(x)=g(f(g(x)))=-\lfloor{-x}\rfloor$. And as you can probably guess, it is equivalent to $\lceil{x}\rceil$.

Comment: What do these brackets mean? ⌊ ⌋

Comment: Those brackets mean *Floor* (nearest smaller integer).

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

- $f(x)=\lfloor{x}\rfloor$
- $g(x)=-x$
- $h(x)=g(f(g(x)))=-\lfloor{-x}\rfloor$

Therefore:

- $h( 3.4)=-\lfloor{-3.4}\rfloor=-(-4)= 4$
- $h( 7  )=-\lfloor{-7  }\rfloor=-(-7)= 7$
- $h(-1.3)=-\lfloor{ 1.3}\rfloor=-( 1)=-1$

And as you can probably understand by now, $h(x)=\lceil{x}\rceil$.

Comment: @Sv7: You're welcome :)